# Configuring Win10 updates to run at a specific time

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-10, windows-update, automatic-updates

I'm currently in the process of migrating some of our systems from Win7 to Win10. One of the requirements of this migration is that any systems running Win10 will need to conform to a specific update policy we had in the past (Win7 machines).

Based on this policy, all the machines in question were scheduled to check/download/install and restart due to Windows Updates on a specific date and time (e.g. Monday at 05:00am).

I am trying to achieve the same functionality on Win10 but I have been unsuccessful in getting to work correctly.

I have tried the following so far:

1) Tried to set some arbitrary active hours, with the notion of setting a custom Restart Option afterwards. This has been unsuccessful due to the fact that the option in question is not enabled (also I can't seem be able to get it to work).

2) Tried the old school way which is by performing the various group policy edits by hand. With this in mind I have set the following options:

```
AUOptions to 4 - Automatically download and scheduled installation
NoAutoUpdate to 0 - Enabling auto updates
ScheduledInstallDay to 2 - Thus meaning Monday
ScheduledInstallTime to 5 - Thus meaning 5am
```

All these options should have granted a behavior similar to the old Win7 setting of installing updates on a specific date and time. Unfortunately it seems that this is not the case.

I have read and followed many guides online stating that they fix the problem in question, but I have yet to find something that suits my needs.

Based on the above, the questions are two:

1) How can I actively tell Windows 10 to install updates on the day and time I specify?

2) How can I productively test my setup to verify whether these changes have taken effect?

Comment: Can you share the results of `rsop.msc` on any of the client system (Windows 10)? Please share the policy section relevant to Windows Update only.